# Should the information on match slips be protected?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

At my LGS they have started used match slips for bigger events such a prereleases. After the event the store has been placing these slips in their scrap paper bin. So they can use the back for notes, life total sheet, etc..

These match slips contain a certain level of information about players, their name and DCI number and signature. I've been thinking about it and there is a possibility this information could be considered sensitive. Thus the store should not reuse these slips there to protect people's information. I've looked through all the rules documents I can find but I can't locate any guidance on this.

Comment: Issues such as privacy of personal information aren't governed by WotC or the DCI, but by laws of the respective state and/or country. Even without such a requirement to treat such information with care, what's the harm in just destroying the info?

Comment: Well, you have to be identified somehow, I guess?! And in my experience people at your local LGS know you anyhow, so why make such a fuss about your name? Also, there is always the option to not partake in tournaments.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a privacy / legal question only tangentially related to board/card games.

Comment: This is privacy law related so it depends on your country.

Answer (score 2):

What information are you worried about being exposed on this scrap paper that has your name and dci number? If you are really concerned the only thing you can do is ask that the shop destroys them. But it would be much better to not have that information on the slips in the first place. If this is a privacy concern after the fact it should also be a privacy concern during the event as well.

During a tournament like this there is no reason whatsoever for the match slips to need to include the players name and dci number. All of that information can be kept in a separate list by the organizers and each player is given a randomly assigned number that can be linked back to the name/dci number after the event for any updates that are needed.

In reality there is no need for your dci number during the event at all as it is just needed during signup and at the end for administrative purposes.

Comment: But... The match slips *do* have name and DCI number. What action do you suggest the author take? (Also I'll note there's a bit of a difference between a controlled piece of paper during an event vs leaving it around in the shop for whoever/whenever.)

Comment: As above, the entire problem is that this information **was** included. This doesn't help the OP to handle the situation at all, hence, how does it answer the question?

Comment: @doppelgreener What do you expect us to be able to suggest other than having them ask the shop to destroy the slips after use which the shop can decide to not do. The simple fact is that the privacy has already been violated by putting them on the sheets in the first place and I would be much more concerned about getting that changed than what happens to them after the fact.

Comment: @JoeW I expect answers to practical problems like this to contain an actionable solution, that's all. (Keyword actionable.)

Comment: @doppelgreener and I edited in what they can do. Outside of providing more information on where they live not much can be suggested. If they live in the EU this might be a GDPR issue.

Comment: As that this website is tailored to a global audience I think a the question would be more useful if it were country independent. It is also less of a concern during an event because a the two players on a slip should be the only ones besides tournament officials that handle the slip, thus only exposing the information of each player to their opponent whereas after the fact the wider public as access.

Comment: @Fr33dan When some countries have extremely stick privacy laws and others don't it can make a big difference in what answer works for the person. As in it could mean the game shop is in legal trouble for keeping the information or there could be no legal issue at all. As for during the event what is there to stop someone else from seeing the information and recording it with a picture or other means.